# How to change the :class name on the view file from a component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently have two active themes using Tailwind `light-theme` and `dark-theme` but I can't make it work within an external button component, just with the code and function inside the view.

This is just an example where the function inside the view is acceptable but I have a "real world" case where I need it working from the component, changing the class between dark/light mode.

Here is my "`Home.vue`" file importing `ButtonA` and `ButtomB`:

```
<template>
  <div :class="theme" class="bg-background-primary">
    <h1 class="text-4xl text-typo-primary">Test title</h1>

    <!-- Inside Home.vue - WORKING -->
    <button class="border border-gray-400 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white p-2 rounded" @click="toggleThemeOne()">Toggle Dark/Light</button>
    <!-- Component with function outside - WORKING -->
    <ButtonA msg="From component" @click.native="toggleThemeTwo()" />
    <ButtonB msg="Full from component" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src

import ButtonA from '@/components/ButtonA.vue'
import ButtonB from '@/components/ButtonB.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    ButtonA,
    ButtonB
  },
  data() {
    return {
      theme: 'theme-light',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleThemeOne() {
      this.theme = this.theme === 'theme-light' ? 'theme-dark' : 'theme-light'
      localStorage.setItem('theme', this.theme)
      console.log('toggleThemeOne working');
      console.log(this.theme)
    },
    toggleThemeTwo() {
      this.theme = this.theme === 'theme-light' ? 'theme-dark' : 'theme-light'
      localStorage.setItem('theme', this.theme)
      console.log('toggleThemeTwo working');
      console.log(this.theme)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

*Home.vue has a working button that's changing the theme*

**ButtonA**

It has the HTML only and the function applied on the component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="border border-gray-400 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white p-2 rounded"> {{ msg }} </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "ButtonComp",
    props: [
        'msg'
    ]
}
</script>
```

**ButtonB**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button
            class="border border-gray-400 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white p-2 rounded"
            @click="toggleThemeTree()"
        > {{ msg }} </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "ButtonComp",
    props: [
        'msg'
    ],
    methods: {
        toggleThemeTree() {
            this.theme = this.theme === 'theme-light' ? 'theme-dark' : 'theme-light'
            localStorage.setItem('theme', this.theme)
            console.log('toggleThemeTree working');
            console.log(this.theme)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

This is the one that's not working. the function should change the :class on Home.vue but I only get the values on the console and the `:class` isn't working.

I did try with `$emit` and `computed property` before but It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass theme to ButtonB component in Home.vue:

```
<ButtonB msg="Full from component" :theme.sync="theme" />
```

Then in ButtonB component, emit the value back to parent on click:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "ButtonComp",
    props: [
        'msg',
        'theme'
    ],
    methods: {
        toggleThemeTree() {
            let theme = this.theme === 'theme-light' ? 'theme-dark' : 'theme-light' // Do not change this.theme directly
            localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
            this.$emit('update:theme', theme)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I got it working updating the let theme to "let theme = this.theme = this.theme === 'theme-light' ? 'theme-dark' : 'theme-light'". Tks